# Changing the hit box position in melonjs

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to follow the platformer tutorial from the melonJS website, but using assets from kenney.nl instead of the tutorial assets. My problem is that the hit box is always centered at the center of the entity, and I need to move it. I've looked through the docs, and I can not figure out how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

if your on an unity based tutorial, you should be able to change how far the collider's center is from the objects center in the inspector, but it would be easier to answer if I knew what engine your using.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply change the anchor point to fix this. Inside the entity constructor, modify the anchor point to match the correct placement using,

```
this.anchorPoint.set(x, y);
```

x and y can be the offsets.

If you are experiencing irregular sprite flipping, simply modify the offsets accordingly in the update function.

https://melonjs.github.io/melonJS/docs/me.Renderable.html#anchorPoint

Comment: Hi, if the code sample is small, try to present in your answer as links usually break.